# How to monitor containers / pods for CarshLoopBackOff state?

Tags: kubernetes, datadog, crashloopbackoff

I have an kubernetes cluster setup and would like to use datadog to monitor the cluster. I want to setup a monitor to alert me if a container/pod is stuck in the CarshLoopBackOff state.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little counter intuitive, but you need to look for pods that are not flagged by pod.ready.  Example find # of failing pods on cluster my-cluster in the default namespace for a monitor:

```
exclude_null(sum:kubernetes_state.pod.ready{condition:false,kube_cluster_name:my-cluster,kube_namespace:default,!pod_phase:succeeded})
```